# How can I distribute turtles by a probability up to a user-defined limit

Tags: netlogo

I'm building a model where I want to distribute animals around a landscape. They have discrete amounts of energy and hence get a variable called `energy`. The landscape has an overall set amount of energy that it could support set at `10950`.

These are the energy categories of the animals: `75, 216, 700, 2500, 5000, 8500, 25000`

And they should appear in the landscape according to the following percentages (or probabilities if we divide by 100): `20.85714667, 7.24206481, 2.23469429, 0.6257144, 0.3128572, 0.18403365, 0.06257144`

I can monitor the amount of energy in the system with:

```
set total_energy sum [energy] of turtles with [shape = "circle"]
```

Every day in the model I want to replenish the animals in the system up to a limit of energy set at 10950.

So the simulation should be populated with animals of the above listed energies according to the probabilities. I don't mind that on occasion a huge animal will be selected that would exceed the limit for the simulation (e.g. if a 25000 energy animal occurs, that will break the threshold which is fine).

It looks like I should combine `while` with the `rnd` extension but I can't quite crack it. Here's what I've got based on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615519/netlogo-weighted-random-draw-from-a-list-how-to-use-rnd-extension):

```
      extensions [ rnd ]
    
      to replenish
      while energy < 10950 [
      let values [1 2 3] ; swap out for mine, should correspond to energy
      let probabilities [0.2 0.3 0.5] ; swap out for mine
      let pairs (map list values probabilities)
      let state first rnd:weighted-one-of pairs [ last ? ] ; how to produce the turtles based on this?
]
    end
```

Comment: A few months ago there was a very similar question about weighted probabilities. I suggest you check that one out. If you still have questions afterwards, I will be glad to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474072/multiple-mutually-exclusive-events-and-probabilities-in-netlogo/73474432#73474432

Comment: See "Lottery Example", in the Code Examples section of the Models Library.